# MYSQL query: Sort by input user based on numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have records in a mysql table.
Users can give their 4-number postal code, the mysql query need to order the results based on the inputted postal code.

For instance three records with the row 'postalcode' > 5000, 5001, 5002
If a user gives 5010 as input the mysql query output needs to be so that the row with 5002 will display first.

Can someone help me out? I tried the search function, but I think i am not using the right english terms to what i mean.

Comment: why would 5010 mean that 5002 is before 5001? is it descending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how exactly your data set is setup.. but you can do a conditional order

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN postalcode < your_code THEN 1
         WHEN postalcode = your_code THEN 2
         WHEN postalcode > your_code THEN 3
         ELSE 4
    END
```

the logic will most likely need to be changed around but that is the general idea.. where 1 is before 2 which is befor 3.. you can change it to mold however you need it to be.. but without data and the table schema i'm limited to just this

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8ba6/3/1)

Comment: I have a tabel called deals.
In that tabel 3 rows.
id - title - postal

example: 
9 - Superdeal - 5001
10 - Dealicious - 6040

When a user submits his 4digit postal, the sql output needs to show the postal digits close to him first. so if user submits 6000 the output needs to be id 10 first and then id 9.